# Cannot set cell.offset value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am reproducing a dummy function which gives me an error 1004 in VBA.
This test function is supposed to take a range and keep writing value of i as string in next column of range.
it stops execution on line 4 silently.
On error reveals error 1004:

```
Function justcheck(rng As Range)
i = 1
  For Each cell In rng
     cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Str(i)
     i = i + 1
  Next
End Function
```

Would appreciate if someone can pinpoint what exactly am I doing wrong.

Comment: What is `rng.Address`? Btw this should likely be a `Sub`, not a `Function`. Also you likely want `CStr`, not `Str`.

Comment: How are you calling this function?  From VBA?

Comment: @BigBen my bad that I made it a function. it is a sub in original code. rng is a  single column vertical selection of cells.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes

Comment: So its address is? What does `Debug.Print rng.Address` return in the Immediate Window? What is the full error message? Is the sheet protected?

Comment: If any cell in your input is close to the right edge of the sheet then maybe you can't offset two columns to the right of that.

Comment: @BigBen B5:B10.   Sheet is not protected.

Comment: Can you show the VBA code that calls this Sub?

Comment: Do you have any merged cells in the sheet? What about pivot tables?

Comment: @BigBen No merged cells

Comment: What's the full error message then?

Comment: @DS_London this is a dummy function. it reproduces the same error.

Comment: @BigBen if we add on error resume next and log err.description it says Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255250/discussion-between-mohsyn-and-bigben).

Comment: Please update your question to add the full code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Tim use this as function anywhere on a blank sheet. pass a range like =justcheck(b5:b10) and check. ideally it should give numbers from 1 to number of rows selected two column from original selection. if not, we have a problem here

Comment: This sounds like you're calling from a worksheet cell, not from VBA. That won't work. User Defined Functions aren't meant to modify cells, but to return a value. If this is a `Sub`, then please create a [reprex].

Comment: Functions called from a worksheet are restricted from doing pretty much anything other than returning a value (or array of values) to the calling cell - seems like that is your problem.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value.

Comment: @TimWilliams this is certainly the issue with this example. in the original code function is passing range to a sub which does the value changes. I am assuming that when a function is called it kind of locks the sheet until function ends and hence the sub fails as well. Please share your reply as answer for me to accept. Also Thanks BigBen for your help!

Comment: There are a number of previous questions where this was the root problem - I've closed this question as a duplicate of one of those.